# Accept vs AcceptTCP

Tags: go

Could someone explain why Go's net package has func (l *TCPListener) Accept() (Conn, error) and func (l *TCPListener) AcceptTCP() (*TCPConn, error) when TCPConn is?

```
type TCPConn struct {
        conn
}
```

Above from tcpsock_posix.go.

What's advantage of having a function which returns *TCPConn over Conn?

Answer (score 2):

The answer is easy, the type net.Conn is an interface and the type net.TCPListener is a struct that implements the net.Conn interface, means that it can be used as a net.Conn type, [see go documentation on interface](https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#interfaces_and_types).

And net.**c**onn != net.**C**onn.